# JSON error while getting data from MYSQL (JSONException: End of input at character 0)

Tags: php, android, api, android-asynctask, android-json

I am trying to get data from mySQL database to my android application via JSON and display them in a ListView. But I'm getting a JSONException. If this is not the best way to get data from a database and display on a ListView, please help me find other ways to do this. I am new to android programming.

```
public class ListTest extends ListActivity {
    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/shareity/include/get_all.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "eid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "ename";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_events);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListTest.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListTest.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ListTest.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListTest.this,
                            productsList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                                    TAG_PID, TAG_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.pid,
                                    R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
 Error parsing data         org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
     FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
     Process: com.example.shareity,     PID: 3556
     java.lang.RuntimeException: An     error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at     android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by:     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method     'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.shareity.ListTest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(ListTest.java:134)
        at com.example.shareity.ListTest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(ListTest.java:1)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        ... 4 more
```

And this is my php API

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once 'DB_Connect.php'; 
// connecting to db
    $this->db = new DB_Connect();
    $this->db->connect();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM event") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["event"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $event = array();
    $event["eid"] = $row["eid"];
    $event["ename"] = $row["ename"];
    //$event["edesc"] = $row["edesc"];
    //$event["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
    //$event["createdBy"] = $row["createdBy"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["event"], $event);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did u try this http://10.0.2.2/shareity/include/get_all.php in your browser?

Comment: post your JSON output..

Comment: @Prag'sシ I am not getting any JSON output. My JSON output is supposed to be data from my DB.

Comment: @Amsheer yeah I tried it. I am getting a message "No database selected". But I have properly configured everything. IDK why I'm getting this message

Comment: @Amsheer ok now I'm getting an error saying "SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'event'". WHY? Please help

Comment: Check your database permissions(MYSQL user permission).

Answer (score 0):

the problem is probably you not connecting to database and the result is you getting Nullpointer Exception. you should :

- check the database connection setting on DB_Connect.php
- check all .php files in htdocs folder (maybe you missing other .php files)

or alternatively you can use my JSONFunctions class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONFunctions {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = null;
    static HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

    //GET
    public static JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
            HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet( url);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ee) {
            Log.i("UnsupportedEncodingException...", is.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i("ClientProtocolException...", is.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("IOException...","error");
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8); //old charset iso-8859-1
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            reader.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.i("StringBuilder...", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
            } catch (Exception e0) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser0", "Error parsing data [" + e0.getMessage()+"] "+json);
                Log.e("JSON Parser0", "Error parsing data " + e0.toString());
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(1));
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser1", "Error parsing data [" + e1.getMessage()+"] "+json);
                    Log.e("JSON Parser1", "Error parsing data " + e1.toString());
                    try {
                        jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(2));
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        Log.e("JSON Parser2", "Error parsing data [" + e2.getMessage()+"] "+json);
                        Log.e("JSON Parser2", "Error parsing data " + e2.toString());
                        try {
                            jObj = new JSONObject(json.substring(3));
                        } catch (Exception e3) {
                            Log.e("JSON Parser3", "Error parsing data [" + e3.getMessage()+"] "+json);
                            Log.e("JSON Parser3", "Error parsing data " + e3.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
```

//POST
         public static JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params) {

```
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "utf-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                Log.e("JSON", json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);           
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

        }         
}
```